# I tried changing javac.sublime-build-package and i got notification access denied

Tags: java, sublimetext3, javac, java-package

I was trying to change javac file text
but it was not changing
so I tried to delete and replace it with the below text copy
when I tried deleting javac in Sublime java package
it pops up notification "*access denied*".
How can I replace it?

```
{
"cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","java", "$file_base_name"],
"file_regex": "^(...?):([0-9]):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.java",
"shell": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to adjust an existing package, you shouldn't try to overwrite the original files. Think about it, once the package updates to a newer version, your changes will be gone.

Instead, Sublime Text offers different ways to customize packages – as mentioned in the [Package Control documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/customizing_packages):

> If a package for Sublime Text 3 is installed as a packed package, it
> should be possible to directly override individual non-python files.
> To do this, create a Packages/{Package Name}/ folder and save
> customized versions of the files with the same name they are in the
> .sublime-package file.

As mentioned by MattDMo, you can also create by additional build systems by saving the to `Packages/User`. You will then be able to select them from the build menu.

On a side note, make sure that your `.sublime-build` file is valid JSON – the `enter code here` part in your example makes it invalid!

Comment: Just as a note, it's not Package Control that provides this functionality; the Sublime core loads packages like this natively (so, it will still work even in the absence of PC, though it seems unlikely that anyone would  be in such a situation).

Comment: You might also want to mention that you can save new build systems, etc. in the `Packages/User` folder. They won't override the same file in a `.sublime-package` file, but they'll still show up in the Build menu.